# Synchronize recording of three cameras with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspbian, v4l2

I am trying to make the video that is recorded from three usb webcams be synchronized, I am using this command, but I still have differences by milliseconds or seconds. Any idea how to achieve it?

```
ffmpeg -y -copyts \
-f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -input_format mjpeg -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 \
-f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -input_format mjpeg -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video2 \
-f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -input_format mjpeg -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video4 \
-map 0:v -c:v copy output1.mkv -map 1:v -c:v copy output2.mkv -map 2:v -c:v copy output3.mkv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to try:

- Save to .mov, not .mkv.  That might reduce CPU load and behave better with `-c:v copy`.
- Write three separate shell scripts, each of which reads one camera and writes one video file.  Run them with `parallel sh ::: 1.sh 2.sh 3.sh`.
- Try `clvc` instead of `ffmpeg`.  To get that, `apt install vlc-bin`.

Others have fought long battles with similar configurations:
[Capturing multiple RTSP streams simultaneously in sync](https://superuser.com/questions/671380/capturing-multiple-rtsp-streams-simultaneously-in-sync)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690806/ffmpeg-how-to-record-multiple-rtmp-streams-into-multiple-files
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-998658-start-0.html

Comment: With Parallel you can achieve synchronization. Thanks for your help.